# Indexing numpy array with list of slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a list of `slices` and use them to index a `numpy` array.

```py
arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

slice_list = list(map(lambda i: slice(i, i+2), [1, 2]))
# [slice(1, 3, None), slice(2, 4, None)]

print(arr[slice_list])
# == arr[1:3, 2:4]
# [[ 7  8]
#  [12 13]]
```

This works fine but it breaks if I have fewer slices than the number of dimensions 
of the array I want to index.

```
arr3d = arr[np.newaxis, :, :]  # dims: [1, 5, 5]
arr3d[:, slice_list]
# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),(`None`) 
#  numpy.newaxis and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

The following examples work however:

```
arr3d[:, slice_list[0], slice_list[1]]
arr3d[[slice(None)] + slice_list]
arr3d[:, [[1], [2]], [2, 3]]
```

Is there a way I can use a list of slices to index an array with more dimensions.
I want to do things like:

```
arr[..., slice_list]
arr[..., slice_list, :]
arr[:, slice_list, :]
```

without thinking about the dimensions of the array and figuring out how many `[slice(None)]*X`
I have to pad on either side of my `slice_list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using tuples of slices and ellipsis objects. Just put all the elements to you want to use for indexing into a tuple and use it as index:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
print(arr)
# [[[ 0  1  2  3]
#   [ 4  5  6  7]
#   [ 8  9 10 11]]
# 
#  [[12 13 14 15]
#   [16 17 18 19]
#   [20 21 22 23]]]
slice_tup = tuple(map(lambda i: slice(i, i+2), [1, 2]))
print(slice_tup)
# (slice(1, 3, None), slice(2, 4, None))
print(arr[slice_tup])
# [[[20 21 22 23]]]

# arr[..., slice_list]
print(arr[(Ellipsis, *slice_tup)])
# [[[ 6  7]
#   [10 11]]
# 
#  [[18 19]
#   [22 23]]]

# arr[..., slice_list, :]
print(arr[(Ellipsis, *slice_tup, slice(None))])
# [[[20 21 22 23]]]

# arr[:, slice_list, :]
print(arr[(slice(None), *slice_tup, slice(None))])
# IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: Ok, but I have to combine the lists/tuples, I can't use `arr[..., slice_tuple, :]` directly?

Comment: @scleronomic No, because that would be the same as `arr[(Ellipsis, (slice(1, 3, None), slice(2, 4, None)), slice(None))]` (that is, a nested tuple). For these cases, it would be nice to have a `*` unpacking syntax, as with function calls, so you could do something like `arr[..., *slice_tup, :]`, but that is not allowed currently (to be fair is kind of a corner case). But you _can_ do `print(arr[(Ellipsis, *slice_tup, slice(None))])`, which is probably a bit nicer (actually I think I will update the answer to use that).